# Bootstrap collapse within a for loop php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like a bootstrap accordion in PHP for a loop. But it doesn't collapse. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$row_count = 1;
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {

  echo $row_count ;
  ?>


  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1<?php echo $row_count; ?>">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1<?php echo $row_count ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 


  <?php
$row_count  ++;
}

?>
```

Comment: shouldn't the panel-group be `outside` of the loop - and just be there once?

Comment: Good shout. I'm not sure whether it needs to be inside or outside loop. What i would like to have is another accordion collapse every time it loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as below:-

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php
$row_count = 1;
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {  ?>

    <div class="panel panel-default" >
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<?php echo $row_count ?>">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $row_count; ?>" aria-expanded="false"">Collapsible Group <?php echo $row_count?></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse<?php echo $row_count; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $row_count; ?>">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php $row_count++; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Every time i click new collapse the previous one does not close.

Comment: Please check now. Just place parent div outside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php  
$row_count = 1;
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
  ?>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne<?=$row_count?>">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?=$row_count?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne<?=$row_count?>">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne<?=$row_count?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?=$row_count?>">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Lorem
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
$row_count  ++;
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but on the page load, all of the sections are collapse are already. I would like all of them to hidden by default.

Comment: just update answer. just replace "panel-collapse collapse in" with "panel-collapse collapse".